# CentOS, Convert ipV6 short to long form

Tags: bash, centos, ipv6

I have just started with bash scripting and there is a small problem which I have to solve to go on:

I'm getting an IPv6 address in this format: 
`1080::8:800:200C:417A`

Now I want to convert the short into the long IPv6 form like: `1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A`

Is there a regex expression or something similar to convert that?

I am working on a docker container which runs on CentOS.

Comment: CentOS 8 is not out yet...

Comment: My suspicion is that writing a single expression to do the translation is probably not feasible.  You have to determine how many groups are missing, which is not a trivial exercise, and then write a replacement using the information about how many groups are missing.  In things like Perl, where you can execute arbitrary (Perl) code in the replacement, it might be more nearly feasible.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't a regex, but it is 'something similar' and it does the job: (tested with python3.5.1)

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> x = '1080::8:800:200C:417A'
>>> y = ipaddress.ip_address(x)
>>> y.exploded
'1080:0000:0000:0000:0008:0800:200c:417a'
>>>
```

Reference:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter the ip address:"
read s
if [[ $s =~ ^(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))$ ]]; then

        echo -e '\E[47;31m'"\033[1mIPv6 Format\033[0m" 
        echo -n "The IPv6 Address Expanded Form:"
        EXPANDED=`sipcalc $s | fgrep Expand | cut -d '-' -f 2`
        echo -e "\033[32m $EXPANDED\033[0m"
        echo -n "IPv6 address Compress Form:"
        Compress=`sipcalc $s | fgrep Comp | cut -d '-' -f 2`
        echo  -e "\033[32m$Compress\033[0m"
        echo -n "Address Type of IPv6:"
        type=`sipcalc $s | fgrep type | cut -d '-'  -f 2,3,4`
        comment=`sipcalc $s | fgrep Comment | cut -d '-' -f 2`
        echo -e "\033[32m $type$comment\033[0m"
else
        echo  -e '\E[37;44m'"\033[1mNOT VALID IPv6 address\033[0m"
fi
```

This is my code for ipv6 validation.U will get the expanded form of ip using "sipcalc".but you should do some grep and cut commands

Comment: Ouch!  As written, it makes a good case for why regexes alone are not a particularly good way of doing the mapping.  You have some interesting (important) special cases at the far right end of a massive regex.  It's feasible to quibble about the literal ffff that appears (shouldn't it allow FFFF too?).  You've not anchored the regex so it matches anywhere in the string.  And you use something else (the `sipcalc` program) to normalize the data, not a replacement operation with the regex.  Well done on having the matching regex available to show, though.

Comment: There are lot of test cases for ipv6 validation.To satisfy that testcases we need some another methods..

Comment: I anchoring the reg ex at beginning of if statement.we can change ffff to [fF]{4}.SO we can solve that..there are lot of another prob to this reg-exp

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I decompress IPv6 address.

```
#!/bin/bash

decompress_ipv6_address() {
    # How many hextets are there
    num_hextets=${addr//[^:]/}
    num_hextets=${#num_hextets}

    # Fix up beginning and end
    [[ $addr =~ ^:: ]] && addr='0'$addr
    [[ $addr =~ ::$ ]] && addr=$addr'0'

    # Create additional hextets
    additional_hextets=':'
    for (( i=$num_hextets; $i<8; i++ ))
    do
        additional_hextets=$additional_hextets'0:'
    done

    # Insert additional hextets (replace ::)
    addr=${addr/::/$additional_hextets}
}
```

Comment: This does not work for mixed IPv6 addresses. Also, "hextet" would be for six bits, as octet is for eight bits or quartet is for four bits. You are dealing with 16-bit words (hexadectets).

Comment: You will note that the function name is "decompress_ipv6_address".  Not "decompress_ipv6_mixed_address".
"Hextet in computing is a sixteen-bit aggregation, or four nibbles."  A nibble is 4-bits.  "A hextet is the unofficial name for each of the 8 blocks in an IPv6 address."  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hextet

Comment: Mixed IPv6 addresses are still valid IPv6 addresses, and they can also be compressed. A good decompression would take into account compressed and mixed IPv6 addresses, too. A 16-bit word is a hexadectet. A hextet is six bits. For example, the TCP flags are a hextet (six bits) in the TCP header. Hex is six, oct is eight, and quad is four, but hexadec is 16. Properly, in the network world, we simply call them words, and an IPv6 address is 8 words

Comment: You can spend your life on petty little arguments like it's a hexadectet... but it is still going to be called a hextet in computing.

Comment: The question specifically cites non-mixed compressed format to uncompressed only.  It so happens that is also what I need and so have provided.  If the person, or anyone else, needs mixed it is minor change to add that.  No one has claimed ipv4 mapped ipv6 is not valid.  But that doesn't mean we all need to handle it in our specific use case and environments.

Comment: Actually, the RFCs require applications to accept any valid IPv6 address format as defined by RFC 4291, but should only display them as defined by RFC 5952: "_all implementations MUST accept and be able to handle any legitimate [RFC4291] format.  It is advised that humans also follow these recommendations when spelling an address._" For example, the (huge) company where I work will test for RFC 5952 compliance, and it will reject any application or device that does not follow the standards track RFC 5952, and other companies do the same thing.

Comment: LOL
RFCs are not legal binding documents.  Besides we are not discussing an application here.  We are discussing a single function of a script in regard to a specific question of how to decompress a non-mixed ipv6 address.  It does not preclude any other processing of any application.
I checked with the boss.  He said we don't have to handle ipv4 mapped addresses because we are public Internet facing and those addresses are not supposed to be on the public Internet.
You just being argumentative.  You pivot from one argument to another.  For whatever reason it seems to give you your jollies.